# nodejs - Is it possible to run a node script located in a folder mentioned in path environment variable without giving absolute path to that file?

Tags: node.js, windows

There is a folder `C:/commandline_shortcuts` in my PC which I already added to environment variable `Path`. I use this folder to put tiny batch scripts that I can run from any directory which works perfectly fine. Today I created a node script, which I want to put in this folder for the same purpose. It only works when I run

`D:/someOtherFolder> node C:/commandline_shortcuts/my-script cmdLineArg1 cmdLineArg2`

but I want to run it like

`D:/someOtherFolder> node my-script cmdLineArg1 cmdLineArg2`

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because `node` is the actual command, not `my-script`.

You can create a `my-script.sh` in the shortcut folder which runs

```
C:/commandline_shortcuts/my-script $1 $1
```